# GTK# Pixbuf Icon in TreeView

Tags: c#, image, treeview, gtk, pixbuf

I am trying to load icons/images from the web and put them into my TreeView. I have the following code (below) but each time it is run it throws an exception. I don't understand what I have done wrong here. Would you please be able to help me to write the correct code?

```
public void ImgCellRenderer(Gtk.TreeViewColumn column, Gtk.CellRenderer cell, Gtk.TreeModel model, Gtk.TreeIter iter)
{
    Gdk.Pixbuf icon = Gdk.PixbufLoader.LoadFromResource("http:\\\\www.free-icons-download.net\\images\\strawberry-icon-37824.png").Pixbuf;
    (cell as Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = icon;
}
```

The exception in full is:

```
    System.ArgumentException: 'http:\\www.free-icons-download.net\images\strawberry-icon-37824.png' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'MDM, Version=1.0.5862.27549, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00051] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/gtk-sharp-2.12.21/gdk/generated/PixbufLoader.custom:104 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00020] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/gtk-sharp-2.12.21/gdk/generated/PixbufLoader.custom:94 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.LoadFromResource (System.String resource) [0x00007] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/gtk-sharp-2.12.21/gdk/generated/PixbufLoader.custom:142 
  at MDM.TweetSelectorWidget.ImgCellRenderer (Gtk.TreeViewColumn column, Gtk.CellRenderer cell, TreeModel model, TreeIter iter) [0x00006] in /Users/tribehive/Projects/MDM/MDM/TweetSelectorWidget.cs:160 
  at GtkSharp.TreeCellDataFuncWrapper.NativeCallback (IntPtr tree_column, IntPtr cell, IntPtr tree_model, IntPtr iter, IntPtr data) [0x0002c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/gtk-sharp-2.12.21/gtk/generated/GtkSharp.TreeCellDataFuncNative.cs:57 
  at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException (System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal) [0x0003b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/gtk-sharp-2.12.21/glib/ExceptionManager.cs:58 
  at GtkSharp.TreeCellDataFuncWrapper.NativeCallback (IntPtr tree_column, IntPtr cell, IntPtr tree_model, IntPtr iter, IntPtr data) [0x00051] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-64/bockbuild-
```

Comment: Use `/` for URLs, not `\​`.

Comment: I've changed it to / and still it doesn't work

Comment: Ah, I see. `LoadFromResource()` does not take a generic URL; it requires you to provide the resource as an assembly resource. I'm not sure what that means for Gtk#. From what I can gather, you'll need to open the URL as a System.IO.Stream to load it. (I'm pretty sure vanilla GdkPixbuf has a function for this, but I'm not quite sure how Gtk# uses GdkPixbuf at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve it! @andlabs was correct in saying you can achieve this by creating a stream to load it. But this involves the creation of many objects (`Stream`, `BinaryReaders`, `BinaryWriters`, etc). *Please see his comment for details. Thanks for your help andlabs.*

The easier way to achieve this is with a `WebClient`. You will notice that you can create a Gdk.Pixbuf from a `byte[]`. So, to create a pixbuf from a downloaded image:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] image = webClient.DownloadDate(url);
Gdk.Pixbuf myPixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(image);
```